# How can my eCommerce site only showcase products without an Add to cart option?

Tags: 7

I want my Drupal eCommerce site to only show products which contain only product name, description, PDF file.

I don't want price & Add to cart options. Is there any possibility in Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a possibility. You can achieve that by using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

Create a content type for Products (say products) or you can also use default content types Basic Page or Article .

Add fields whatever you want to show for products (say description, file for PDF).

Create a *View* for to display the Product content type nodes (products)

> You need Views if
>
> - You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort    it differently.
> - You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to    sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
> - You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain    type.
> - You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display    articles the way you like.
> - You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of    some particular type.
> - You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
> - You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable    Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of
>     "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and
>     displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts
>     for that month.
>
> Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some of the obvious
>   uses of Views.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any possibility to use enquiry form in that view for each and every prodcut?

Comment: Its not a new question. Am having doubt in previous your explanation.

Comment: Tamil Vaalga..then how can reply only regarding this question?